# Custom Message Body : PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

How can i edit and modify the default message body of PHPMailer emails. I want to set a custom html page as phpmailer message, matching to my website UI with user account activation link. Please let me know is it possible or not and if yes, how to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Er, like this:

```
$mail->Body = 'your HTML here';
```

Bear in mind that much HTML and CSS does not work well in email, but you're free to do what you like.